# Prove that $2^n+3^n $ is never a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

My attempt :

If $n$ is odd, then the square must be 2  (mod 3), which is not possible.

Hence $n =2m$

$2^{2m}+3^{2m}=(2^m+a)^2$

$a^2+2^{m+1}a=3^{2m}$

$a (a+2^{m+1})=3^{2m} $

By fundamental theorem of arithmetic,

$a=3^x $

$3^x +2^{m+1}=3^y $

$2^{m+1}=3^x (3^{y-x}-1) $

Which is not possible by Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic

Is there a better method? I even have a nagging feeling this is wrong as only once is the equality of powers of 2 and 3 $(n) $are used.

Comment: who is $a$ in the first equality? Why can you write $2^{2m} + 3^{2m} = (2^m +a)^2$?

Comment: @Ant because the LHS is supposed to be a perfect square..

Comment: @Ant Assuming $2^{2m}+3^{2m}$ is a perfect square, say $b^2$, set $a=b-2^m$. Then $2^{2m}+3^{2m}=b^2=(2^m+a)^2$.

Comment: Looks surprisingly simple, but I can't see any real mistake. I think you also have to deal with $x=0$ case though.

Comment: @Wojowu isnt there was some conjecture which states $2^m+1=3^n$ for only (3,2) ?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN It is a special case of Catalan's conjecture (now known as Mihailescu's theorem). But there is no need for that, since we get the equation $1+2^{m+1}=3^{2m}$, while RHS is clearly larger.

Comment: oh thank you. I misunderstood your proof :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Work $\pmod 3$.  We see that $$2^n+3^n\equiv 2^n\pmod 3$$ from which we quickly deduce that your expression is only a square $\pmod 3$ if $n$ is even.

Now work $\pmod 5$.  We see that $$2^n+3^n\equiv 2^n+(-2)^n\equiv 2^n(1+(-1)^n)\pmod 5$$ from which we deduce that your expression is only a square $\pmod 5$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Sorry how did you deduce n is odd in the second case?

Comment: @N.S.John $2^{n}(1+(-1)^{n}) \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$ if $n$ is even. But $\pm 2$ are non-quadratic residues modulo $5$.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  If $n=2k$ then $2^n$ is a square (obviously) but $(1+(-1)^n)=2$ and $2$ is not a square $\pmod 5$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your method is slightly wrong, as you have to deal with the $x=0$ case. However, the remaining diophantine equation is simple.

Here, I provide you with an alternative approach, though admittedly yours seems better.

For the case $m \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, note that $$2^{2m}+3^{2m}=n^2$$ implies that $2^m=2ab$, and $3^m=a^2-b^2$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1, a \not \equiv b \pmod 2$. This implies that $a=2^{m-1}, b=1$. So all that remains is finding $m,y$ such that $3^{m}=2^{2m-2}-1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is more convoluted than your way, but I already wrote it so I'll just leave it here :-)

$4^m = (a-3^m)(a+3^m) \implies a-3^m = 2^p, a+3^m = 2^q$ with $p+q = 2m$. Note that $q \ge p$

Then $a = 2^p + 3^m = 2^q - 3^m  \iff 2^p (2^{q-p}-1) = 2\cdot 3^m$

But then it must be $p=1$, $q = 2m-1$, and we have

$$2^{2(m-1)}-1 = (2^{m-1}-1)(2^{m-1}+1) = 3^m$$

Since only one of the factors in the LHS can be divisible by $3$, it means the other one must be $1$, hence we get $2^{m-1}-1 = 1 \implies m = 2$

But in this case $2^{m-1}+1 = 3 \neq 3^2 $, so this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach.

For the odd case of $n$, as you mentioned the result is  $2\mod 3$ which cannot be a square number.

As for the even case $n=2m$, we have $2^{2m}+3^{2m}\mod 10$ being equal to $2$ (for when $m=0$) or either $3$ (for $n=2+4k,k\geq0$) or $7$ (for $n=4k,k\geq1$), which clearly cannot be square (as a square number modulus $10$ takes values $0,1,4,9,6,5$).

Comment: The nice thing about this argument is it can be explained to a grade-schooler: the last digit of $4^m$ follows the pattern $4,6,4,6,\ldots$ and the last digit of $9^m$ follows the pattern $9,1,9,1,\ldots$, so $4^m+9^m$ always ends in $3$ or $7$ (ignoring $m=0$), and no square ends in $3$ or $7$.